# Why is TypeScript complaining about array length?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a method that accepts 2 to 4 arguments:

```
myMethod(a: string, b: string, c?: any, d?: number);
```

In a unit test, I try to pass arguments to the method this way:

```
const args: [string, string, any, number] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 0];
myMethod(...args);
```

Even though I declared `args` to be of a set length, the TypeScript compiler shows this error:

> TS2556: Expected 2-4 arguments, but got 0 or more.

Why is this error shown? Is there anything I can do to keep the last line (the function call) as it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that this issue no longer occurs in TS3.0+, see [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoa0C2BPAsgKYAuAFvACYAUYAXNBMQE4CWAdgOYA00ARvY1acewAPz0wbXDwrjobAK7ZehJgEoU0AL4YsAM0RUNaTFmjB4bRtDBMOEegG1B7bg2auek6fKUqmALrQALzQjgDkYOE84bzR0OHA8QAMAQDcumZkLBAAdHhEZJRUuaW29moZpjroNRhAA).  Previous answer:

---

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4130), and the short answer for why it happens is that rest/spread support in TypeScript was originally designed for arrays and not tuples.

You can wait for [tuples in rest/spread positions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) to be supported in TypeScript; it's supposedly going to be introduced starting in [TypeScript 3.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#30-july-2018) which should come out soon.

Until then, your only options are workarounds.  You could abandon the spread syntax and pass the arguments one by one:

```
myMethod(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);  // type safe but not generalizable
```

or assert that your method accepts `...args: any[]` as in:

```
(myMethod as (...args:any[])=>void)(...args);  // no error, not type safe
```

or ignore the error,

```
// @ts-ignore
myMethod(...args); // no error, not type safe
```

EDIT: or use the [not-currently-well-typed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/212) `apply()` method (which, unlike the previous two workarounds, changes the emitted js):

```
myMethod.apply(this, args); // no error, not type safe
```

None of those are great, so if waiting for the feature to be implemented is an option you might want to do that.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help, and for directing me to the right thread on github.  I've changed my execution to `myMethod.apply(this, args);` but I lose type-safety.  It was either that or your last suggestion, because I don't want to modify the method itself and I need the call to be generic so passing the args one at a time wouldn't work.

Comment: Accepting this answer. Suggest you add my solution (in my post above this one) as another alternative if you find it acceptable.